# Can a Moros mage use Sculpt Ephemera to enhance items indefinitely?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

A mage with Death 3 can open a gate to Twilight and bring some raw iron with him. Same mage can sculpt any ephemeral object in twilight to enhance its durability, shape, damage, armor as a lasting spell with sculpt ephemera. That said mage can then go back to fallen world and use that said item indefinitely without the need of relinquishing. This item can theoretically be a dagger with 5 damage or a leather jacket with more armor than a flak jacket.

Is there some rule that would prevent this scenario from happening? It really seems too overpowered considering the requirements and cost of enchanted items. And what about the Shadow Realm -- can ephemeral items created in Twilight be used there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the following are Death rotes from *Mage: the Awakening*:

- **Ghost Gate** (Death •••) allows the mage to cross over into Twilight, becoming a Twilight being and interact with objects and denizens there.
- **Ghostly Object** (Death •••) allows you to turn a real world item (like your hunk of iron) into a Twilight object by utterly destroying it in the real world.
- **Sculpt Ephemera** (Death •••) allows you to take a Twilight object and reshape or enhance it, with successes going to durability first, then other bonuses.
- **Touch of the Ghost** (Death ••) allows you to use Twilight items in the real world. (Note that the duration here is "Prolonged," rather than Lasting.)

So, to accomplish what you want to do, you'd first need to destroy the lump of iron and cast **Ghostly Object** on it. Then, you'd cast **Ghostly Gate** to enter Twilight, and **Sculpt Ephemera** to give it the shape and bonuses you want. **Ghostly Gate** back out again, and use **Touch of the Ghost** to use the item for a duration contingent on the number of successes you got. That's four spells to accomplish something that could be done pretty easily with Matter — the *other* Moros Ruling Arcanum.

It sounds like you've assumed that going into Twilight through a **Ghostly Gate** turns all the things you have into ephemeral items as well. Based on the requirements of **Ghostly Object**, there's no reason to believe that's true; you'd need some kind of Matter-Death conjunctional effect to pull that off, and if you've got that much Matter, you can bonus up your stuff directly.

Twilight is part of the Material World — it, too, is separated from the Shadow by the Gauntlet. You'd need Spirit 3 to lay down a pathway between the two worlds to get the Ephemera there. Once it's there, yes, you can use the Ephemeral Object in Shadow just as you could in Twilight.

Comment: thanks. just a quick question, how about shadow realm? can the said mage use objects created with ghostly object and sculpted with sculpt ephemera in shadow realm?

Comment: This may well be worth asking as a separate question, but the answer is that Twilight is part of the Material World — it, too, is separated from the Shadow by the Gauntlet. You'd need Spirit 3 to lay down a pathway between the two worlds to get the Ephemera there. Once it's there, yes, you can use the Ephemeral Object in Shadow just as you could in Twilight.

Comment: @Jadasc you should probably encourage questions like that to be asked as such, or amended to the question, so that our answer mechanisms can apply and so as to not encourage bad habits in a user. ;)

Comment: Quite right. @VolkanUlukut, the proper StackExchange way would be to ask that as a separate question, as comments are meant to be temporary. I'm going to amend your question to work this exchange in.